# Ask question/unanswered links are superimposed when logged out on the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If I’m not logged in on the main site, then the “Unanswered” and “Ask question” links are superimposed in the menu in the header. Here’s a screenshot which illustrates the behaviour:

[image]

Hovering over the superimposed item, the “Ask question” link gets highlighted.

The behaviour doesn’t occur on your Meta site. I assume the menu is supposed to be the same, whether or not you’re logged in, but at the moment it isn’t.

I can reproduce the bug in the latest versions of Safari and Chrome, running no third-party extensions, in OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: That's bizarre.

Comment: Reproduced. Still bizarre.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller There's a styling specific to anonymous users, for some reason: `#header.headeranon #hmenus .askquestion { top: 92px; }`. Should probably just be removed.

Comment: Happens to me too, also under Mac OSX. Can confirm for Firefox too.

Comment: @abby as a CM can't you pull some strings to have it fixed? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops. You're quite right - that shouldn't be happening.

Will be fixed in the next build.